# Are there Logical Route Names in Angular 2/4/5?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Whenever I have to rework the URL scheme in an Angular app router, my various `router.navigate()` invocations break because they have to contain the same "URL encode logic" as the router "URL decode logic".
Is there a "DRY" way to define routes (maybe using logical route names, rather than actual URL fragments) such that the same definition will work with the router and the various `navigate()` references thruout the app code?

Answer (score 0):

Put your route strings in static fields of a class that can be referenced from all calls to `navigate`.

Use child routes to avoid having to define absolute routes when navigating within a module.